# if statement in Django template issue

Tags: python, django, templates, if-statement

I am trying to compare value inside template of django. if statement is not working
here is my code
Model class:

```
class Run(models.Model):
    run_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    run_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    pms_id = models.ForeignKey('ProcessManagementSystem', db_column = 'pms_id')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.run_name 


class ProcessManagementSystem(models.Model):
    pms_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pms_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)

def __unicode__(self):
       return self.pms_name
```

My template

```
{% for run in all_runs %}
        {{run.pms_id}}
        {% if run.pms_id == "PMSName1" %}
                    {{run.pms_id}}
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

the interesting thing is when I am printing {{run.pms_id}} , it is not showing the ID, It is showing pms_name (maybe because of return self.pms_name)

So during compare, I am trying to compare with name i.e. "PMSName1" instead of id But still no luck.
Any suggestion how to compare?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pms_id` is an object so if you want to get the id or the name do something like:

```
{% if run.pms_id.pms_id == 1 %} or {% if run.pms_id.pms_name == "PMSName1" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

A ForeignKey field in Django does not give you simply the ID; it gives you the actual related object. You shouldn't use the `_id` format, because Django actually creates the underlying database column by adding `_id` to the name of the field. So, you have a db column called `pms_id_id`.

In the template, the object is not equal to either the id or the name. You can access the ID field directly:

```
{% if run.pms_id_id == whatever %}
```

or access the id of the related object:

```
{% if run.pms_id.pms_id == whatever %}
```

The advantage of the first form is that it doesn't trigger a db lookup for the related object; the advantage of the second is that you could compare against any of the fields, using eg `run.pms_id.pms_name` for example.